# nginx plugin for certbot official image

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile, alpine-linux, certbot

I am facing issue with official Certbot Docker image not including the NGINX plugin by default. Unfortunately, there seems to be no documentation provided on how to add this plugin to the existing Certbot image. The Alpine repository also lacks the python3-certbot-nginx package, as a result I am not able to create my own custom image using Alpine.

On running the following command inside docker container:

```bash
certbot --nginx -d example.com
```

I am getting the following error

```bash
The requested nginx plugin does not appear to be installed
```

I've researched the Alpine package availability and attempted to add the NGINX plugin using apk within the Certbot Dockerfile, but I encountered an error, indicating the package was not found in the Alpine repository.

Seeking guidance or workarounds:

- Does anyone have insights on how to add the NGINX plugin to the existing official Certbot image?
- Are there alternative approaches or workarounds to install the NGINX plugin within the Certbot Docker container?
- Is there a different Alpine package name or a different method to install the NGINX plugin for Certbot within the Alpine environment?

Appreciate any help or suggestions to resolve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: can you please share your docker build command or Dockerfile whichever you using with certbot docker image?

Answer (score 0):

Since alpine itself doesn't have python3-certbot-nginx package we can use the pip to install the equvivalent of the same.
To add nginx plugin to official certbot image we can do something like this

```
FROM certbot/certbot:latest

RUN pip3 install certbot-nginx
```

Though it does add the nginx plugin to certbot running inside container, we can't use it with certbot as expected if we are running both certbot and nginx as a separate service. Certbot will require access to nginx binary, and path to all the nginx conf file. It might be possible to do so by using bind mounts (still haven't tried due to time constraint). But I instead used webroot to meet my specific usecase.